# Code for method outside the main to get distance of my 3 points

Tags: java, swing, class, point, numberformatexception

So i have a school project which requires me to write code and implement methods to prove that a user inputted set of 3 coordinates will be a certain triangle.

Im trying to write a line of code to get the distance between my 3 points P1, P2, P3. Im not sure how i refer to my established coordinates like x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3.
here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class EpsteinProj3
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
    String input1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter coordinate A");
    String input2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter coordinate B");
    String input3= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter coordinate C");
    System.out.println("Your Triangle is: " + input1 + " " + input2 + " " + input3);

    //double temp = Double.parseDouble(input1);
    //System.out.println("" + temp);

    //double temp1 = Double.parseDouble(input2);
    //System.out.println("" + temp1);

    //double temp2 = Double.parseDouble(input3);
    // System.out.println("" + temp2);

      Double x1, x2, x3;
      Double y1, y2, y3;

      x1 = Double.parseDouble(input1.substring(1, input1.indexOf(",")));
      y1 = Double.parseDouble(input1.substring(input1.indexOf(",") +1, input1.length()-1));
      Point P1 = new Point(x1, y1);

      x2 = Double.parseDouble(input2.substring(1, input2.indexOf(",")));
      y2 = Double.parseDouble(input2.substring(input2.indexOf(",") +1, input2.length()-1));
      Point P2 = new Point(x2, y2);

      x3 = Double.parseDouble(input3.substring(1, input3.indexOf(",")));
      y3 = Double.parseDouble(input3.substring(input3.indexOf(",") +1, input3.length()-1));
      Point P3 = new Point(x3, y3);


      System.out.println("Point A is " + P1.toString());
      System.out.println("Point B is " + P2.toString());
      System.out.println("Point C is " + P3.toString());

      //scalene, isosceles, right


}

public static double distanceBetween()
{
    double Dis1 = Math.sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1- y2)^2);
    Dis1 = Math.sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1- y2)^2);
}

}
```

Comment: What's the exact error and stacktrace?

Comment: That's because parentheses are not a part of a valid number. It should be `input.substring(1, input.indexOf(","))` and `input.substring(input.indexOf(",") + 1, input.length - 1)` to exclude parentheses on both sides.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with the IDE being used. No need to add the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [following](http://fiddle.re/yyyyyyn9wnr) regular expression for parsing point. This allows optional `(` or `)` and optional space after `,`.

Note, this example uses `java.awt.Point`, so you should replace `Integer.parseInt` with `Double.parseDouble` for swing implementation.

```
public class StringToPoint {
private static final Pattern POINT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(?:\\()?([0-9]+)?,(?: )?([0-9]+)?(?:\\))?");

private static Point parsePoint(String point){
    Matcher matcher = POINT_PATTERN.matcher(point);
    if (!matcher.matches() || matcher.groupCount()!=2){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("%s cannot be parsed as point",point));
    }
    return new Point(
        Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)),
        Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2))
    );
}

@Test
public void test(){
    TestCase.assertEquals(new Point(123,456), parsePoint("(123,456)"));
    TestCase.assertEquals(new Point(123,456), parsePoint("(123, 456)"));
    TestCase.assertEquals(new Point(123,456), parsePoint("123, 456"));
    TestCase.assertEquals(new Point(123,456), parsePoint("123,456"));
}
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help but its not exactly what im looking for. Im trying to get the distance between my 3 points P1, P2, and P3. I made a method: public static double distanceBetween(Point P1 , Point P2) to attempt to get the distance between those two points. but inside it i have  double Dis1 = Math.sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1- y2)^2);
        Dis1 = Math.sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1- y2)^2); which is wrong since the x1 and y1 and so on are not recognized

Comment: No, you edited question to ask for distance between point. Original question was about parsing point from String. Please do not edit question to ask another questions, open another question instead. This i why i downvoted your question.

Comment: im new here so sorry if i didnt abide by the rules. I originally made a new question but it made me wait 90 min within asking the first one. I just wanted to find a way to add onto the question. sorry

Answer (score -2):

That because you started reading from the first element of the string.
If you are sure that the format will always be (posX, posY) then

```
  x = Double.parseDouble(input1.substring(1, input1.indexOf(",")));
  y = Double.parseDouble(input1.substring(input1.indexOf(",") +1, input1.length()-1));
```

Comment: How about the last parenthesis?

Comment: But having replaced my x and y code with yours, now my error is: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5.0)"

Comment: Sorry did not remember the last parentesis. See my edited answer @LionelEpstein

Comment: ok that worked, thanks a lot. might have some other questions later that i might refer to here

Comment: I updated my code and now my question is how do i code my method outside the main for distance. I sorta know the syntax for the actual math but how do i refer to my x's and y's from the main if im in a new method.